# Twitter Status update Windows 8 app keep getting unauthorised error

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-8

I am developing windows 8 app, Following is my code for posting to twitter using c# and windows 8

```
        const string oauthVersion = "1.0";
        const string oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";

        var oauthNonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999);
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    consumerKey,
                                    oauthNonce,
                                    oauthSignatureMethod,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauthVersion,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceUrl),
                     "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(ConsumerSecret + "&" + oauth_token_secret, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        MacAlgorithmProvider hmacSha1Provider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
        CryptographicKey macKey = hmacSha1Provider.CreateKey(keyMaterial);
        IBuffer dataToBeSigned = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(baseString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer signatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(macKey, dataToBeSigned);
        String signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);

        const string headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", " +
                                    "oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", " +
                                    "oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", " +
                                    "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(consumerKey),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthNonce.ToString()),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignatureMethod),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthVersion)
                        );

        var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(resourceUrl);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

        byte[] content = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(postBody);

        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(content);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(resourceUrl, byteArrayContent);
        var httpResponseMessage = response.Result;
        var isSuccessStatusCode = httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

It's keep giving unauthorized error,
Please help

Answer (score -1):

Check your code with existing open source Twitter libraries

[Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer)

[TwitterRT](http://twitterrt.codeplex.com/)

[Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)

[TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)

Comment: i tried twitterRt, which suppose to work with windowsRT, but it still gives Unauthorized error. Other libraries wont work because .net version of framework available for windows rt apps does not have many libraries, some of them used for authentication